# Attempting a Sieve of Eratosthenes python function

Tags: python, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm quite new to python/programming and I have been attempting to do a sieve of Eratosthenes function  program however it seems like my code is outputting an undesired outcome. In addition, to this I also do not know understand how the program is outputting that particular solution. May someone please help me and explain the current output and how I should go about and fix this program so that it can print prime numbers instead.

Kind Regards!

```
#Sieve Code 

import math
numbers = []

def sieve_method(n):
    global numbers
    for n in range(2, n + 1):
        for J in range (2, int(math.sqrt(n))+1):
            if J in numbers:
                multiple = n*J 
                while multiple <= n:
                    if multiple in numbers:
                        numbers.remove(n)
                J += multiple
            numbers.append(n)
        print(numbers) 

sieve_method(10)
```

```
#CURRENT OUTPUT 
#[]
#[]
#[4]
#[4, 5]
#[4, 5, 6]
#[4, 5, 6, 7]
#[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
#[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9]
#[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10]
```

Comment: that is not at all sieve of eratosthenes

Comment: It would help greatly if you used more meaningful variable names.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/194762/226167 . You cam find multiple attempts of the  sieve  algorithm on `codereview`  by different people.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
With the meaningless variable names and lack of comments or structure, I don't see how you *think* you're building the sieve.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, since this is not a true implementation of the Sieve of Erathnostenes, but rather just a prime-generating function (which is not exactly a sieving procedure), here is a real sieve algorithm code:

```
def sieve(n):
   sieved = list(range(2, n+1))
   for n in sieved:
       for J in range(2, n+1):
           if n%J==0:
               sieved.remove(n)
               print(sieved)
               break
       print(sieved)
```